# c++ Open file and load data into 2D array through function

Tags: arrays, file-io, 2d, istream

```
void loadData(int a[1000][1000], int row, int col, istream& inData);
```

Above is my function declaration.

I am trying to open a file and load its data into 2d array called `a`.

How can I do this?

What should be my function call in `main`?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far. You will also need to describe the file's data format.

Comment: I only see your function `signature`. Could you copy/paste the entire text of the function (signature + body) `int add(int paramA, int paramB) {...}` ?